# Automate PDF report with Power Bi

Tags: automation, powerbi

I have a Power Bi Pro license and I create a report that contains several pages. I have been asked to create an automated service where the report updates on a monthly basis via an API connection to our DB, then creates a PDF version of the report which gets emailed to various users.

According to my research the automation of creating a PDF and emailing it is not possible with a Pro license and i need to upgrade to Premium ( not an issue ) but further investigation suggests it would only work with a paginated report which ( as far as i'm aware ) would remove features such as text boxes automatically updating the month name etc.

Am i missing something or is there a way around this?

Comment: It would be best to create the report in Paginated type, you can have dynamic text boxes that update the date etc. You'll need a single Premium Per User license, you can then email to you or a mailbox of your choice (or to blob storage, then use automate to send it out), then send it out to the listed users. Or add PPU licenses to your users if the report content itself needs to be dynamic. Use Premium 'A' Skus if you want to save money and turn it on and off when you need it